# FATAL EXCEPTION: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference getItemCount

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

I'm just trying to display all images uploaded to Firebase Storage using a recyclerview. Every time I run my app to test out everything my app crashes and when I check the Logcat it keeps telling me `Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference at com.myapp.yoody.AdapterOne.getItemCount`. I'm just wondering what is the null object its referring to. Is it talking about the fact that it's not connecting to firebase? or what is it? I've been trying for days to get this thing to work and I've got nothing. Please help me out here. I hope my question doesn't sound confusing. Here's my code below. Thanks in advance

```
     //Profilepage (The page where the images are supposed to display)    

           FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
        TextView name;
        DatabaseReference databaseReference;
        StorageReference storageReference;
        private Context mccontext=ProfileActivity.this;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        AdapterOne adapter1;
        String uid;
        // Folder path for Firebase Storage.

        ImageView imageView;

        //List<ImageUploadInfo> list=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ImageUploadInfo> imagesList;
        // Folder path for Firebase Storage.
        String Storage_Path = "Images/";

        // Root Database Name for Firebase Database.
        public static final String Database_Path = "Images";



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
            recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right, R.anim.slide_left);




            adapter1=new AdapterOne(mccontext,imagesList);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);
            imagesList=new ArrayList<>();
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
            uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            // Assign FirebaseStorage instance to storageReference.
            storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            // Assign FirebaseDatabase instance with root database name.
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Database_Path);

            // Adding Add Value Event Listener to databaseReference.

            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){

                        ImageUploadInfo imageUploadInfo=postSnapshot.getValue(ImageUploadInfo.class);
                        imagesList.add(imageUploadInfo);

                    }
                    adapter1 = new AdapterOne(getApplicationContext(), imagesList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);


                }



                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });





        }








        }

       //My Adapter class

       public class AdapterOne extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterOne.ViewHolder> {
        Context context;
        List<ImageUploadInfo> imagesList;

        public AdapterOne(Context c, List<ImageUploadInfo> TempList) {
            imagesList = TempList;
            context = c;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            ImageUploadInfo imageUploadInfo = imagesList.get(position);


            Glide.with(context).load(imageUploadInfo.getImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
             return imagesList.size();


        }



        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public ImageView imageView;

            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                imageView=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            }
        }
    }

     //UploadInfo class

     public class ImageUploadInfo {

   // public String imageName;

    public String imageURL;



    public ImageUploadInfo() {} // default constructor that takes no arguments

    public ImageUploadInfo( String url) {

        this.imageURL= url;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageURL;
    }


    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }
}

   //CardView class

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:rowCount="3">


            <!-- 3 -->


            <!-- 4 -->

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="320dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
                app:cardElevation="0dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/imageview"
                     />

                <!--

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imagename"
                    android:text="Image Name"
                    />
                -->
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Database Structure]

Comment: Please post database structure

Comment: have you tried initializing `imagesList` before passing it to the adapter?

Comment: `adapter1 = new AdapterOne(getApplicationContext(), imagesList);` simply debug this line and check if `imageList` is not null.

Comment: @Ashish I just posted my database structure

Comment: @MohamedMohsin i think I did intalize it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you initialize the list AFTER you send it to adapter. So adapter trying to execute its method on the list which is not exist. Move init lane BEFORE send it in adapter
[image]

Comment: I am so sorry for replying late. I did fix that  but my images still are'nt displaying